# 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?body=1:8707

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Now I am trying to set up ajax search form. My codes doesn't work with an error message.

```
 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?body=1:8707
```

could you tell me how to solve this problem??

☆show.html.erb(members_controller)

```
             <div class= "form">
             <%= form_tag({:action => "show"}, {:method => "get", :remote => true}) do %>
               <div class="from_field_index">
                <%= text_field_tag 'content' %>
               <%= submit_tag '文検索' %>
              <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>

<% @gmsg_users.each do |gmsg| %> 
<div id="result"></div>
<% end %>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

☆members_controller

```
 @gmsg_users = GroupMessage.where(:group_id => join_groups).order("created_at desc").limit(15)
      @gmsg_users.scoped
      if params[:content].present?
        @gmsg_users = @gmsg_users.where("name like ?" ,  "%" + params[:content]  + "%")

      end
```

☆show.js.erb

```
$('#result').html("<%= gmsg.content%>");
```

☆application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tsundoku Buster</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> <!--テキストは:dafaultsに変えよという。-->
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

☆application.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application

    config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)

  end
```

☆gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: see rails server log, and let u know where is the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Some variables caused the error. Thanks again.

Comment: glad to hear that Instruction helps u. :) ...